# How to access .env variables from express in node?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I try to return my env variables in an express file but I get `null`.

This is my folder structure

```
--backend
  --.env
  --src
    --index.ts

--frontend
```

```
//.env
TEST: mytest
```

```
//index.ts
app.get("/api/test", (request, response) => {
  response.send({test: [process.env.TEST]})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `.env`, it should be:

```
TEST=mytest
```

- (If the modification above doesn't work) Since the `.env` is not in the same folder as `index.ts` file, you may need to provide the path to the `.env` file.

At the beginning of your `index.ts` file :

```
require('dotenv').config({path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env')});
```

Answer (score 3):

Install
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

***Usage***
As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

`require('dotenv').config()`

```
// server.js
console.log(`Your port is ${process.env.PORT}`); // undefined
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
console.log(`Your port is ${process.env.PORT}`); // 8626
```

so in your case

```
/src/ 
   index.ts
   .env
```

You can also check for errors

```
const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
```

Comment: still getting undefined. perhaps the .env file is at the wrong place? sorry, I have no clue

Comment: move .env inside src, it will autoload

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by doing two things:

Firstly created `.env` file by using the terminal. ([see reference](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/135#issuecomment-453264342))

Then, I moved `.env` file to the `root` folder of my backend (removing it from `src`)